# Pass parameters to change css

Tags: jquery, css, parameters

I dont get this to work. I want the solution via the changeCSS function so I can pass different properties and values.

```
$("div").on("mouseover", changeCSS("opacity","0.5"));

function changeCSS(prop,val) {
$(this).css(prop, val);
}
```

Comment: This seems pointless to me - Just do `$("div").on("mouseover", function(){ $(this).css("opacity","0.5"); });` ? If not  - Daniel Imms answer is correct

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because when inside `changeCSS`, `this === window`. You should pass in the element as well. Also you need to give `.on()` a function if you want to provide custom arguments.

```
$("div").on("mouseover", function () {
    changeCSS(this, "opacity", "0.5"));
});

function changeCSS(elem, prop, val) {
    $(elem).css(prop, val);
}
```

You may have already done it but you should probably also have a mouseleave event that restores the opacity.

```
$("div").on("mouseleave", function () {
    changeCSS(this, "opacity", "1"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't believe mouseover can be used that way, just a function. i assume you only want the css to change when the mouse is over, and change back after it leaves.. if not you can remove the mouseleave function:

```
$("div").bind("mouseenter",function(){
  changeCSS(this, "opacity", "0.5");
}).bind("mouseleave",function(){
  changeCSS(this, "opacity", "1");
});
function changeCSS(ele, prop,val) {
  $(ele).css(prop, val);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2vhN/